# Jenkins Custom Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**Java is the only possible language for to create Jenkins Plugin?** 
Because, the below references shown It needs Apache Maven, JDK 6.0 above.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-BuildingaPlugin
https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-a-jenkins-plugin-from-scratch-in-5-st

Jenkins means: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Home
Jenkins has its own thousands of plugins for to fulfill user requirements, unfortunately I didn't get exact plugin for my requirement.

**My requirement is to fetch tweets and contents form TWITTER**

Comment: Please let me know... its urgent!

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is built using Java, so yes, plugins are built in Java.

However, you problably don't need to write a custom plugin to do achieve what you're trying to do. What you need is a "Freestyle Job" that will include whatever scripts/commands perform the fetching against Twitter.

Take a look at [Building a Software Project](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project), specifically on **Setting up the Project** (emphasis mine):

> Go to Jenkins top page, select "New Job", then choose "Build a free-style software project". This job type consists of the following elements:
>
> ...
>
> some sort of build script that performs the build (ant, maven, **shell script**, batch file, etc.) where the real work happens

So you can create a build job and add an "Execute shell" build step to kick off your Twitter scraping program. There are countless tutorials found with search terms like "creating a freestyle jenkins job" if you need in-depth step-by-step instructions.

Comment: ThanQ, Especially for Build a free-style software project.. :)